# Class not showing in InterfaceBuilder under custom class, unable to attach my class to an UITableViewController object in IB

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder

**What I did:**

- Created a new `class` called `TableVC` (`Superclass` `UITableViewController`)
- In `IB` I put a `Table View Controller` on the `canvas`.
- In `IB` I selected `Table View Controller` and went to `Identity Inspector`
- Don't see my `class` `TableVC` under `Custom Class`.
- Cleaned the project several times...

**What I've verified:**

- `TableVC` `superclass` is `UITableViewController`
- `File Inspector` shows me that `TableVC.m` is selected for `Target Membership`
- Under `Build Phases` I see that `TableVC.m` is listed in `Compile Sources`.

Now its your part.
Any idea why my `class` is not showing?

Comment: if you force and write by hand TableVC, do it run?

Comment: Strange, I just did it again and now it works. The first time I got unknown class message on the console.